# Spring, Hibernate and multiple references to the same row in database

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, reference, instance

I'm currently facing a problem here and I thought maybe some of you guys could help me out.
I am developing an application using SPRING and HIBERNATE and my issue is the following:

**1** - I first create a new AudioFile object (Domain class) in my main object, and insert it in the database using the hibernateTemplate.save(audioFile) method in the DAO.

**2** - I then use hibernateTemplate.get(1) method of the DAO to retrieve the row from the database, and store the instance into an audioFile1 object. (Of type AudioFile)

**3** - I then repeat **step 2** and store the instance into an audioFile2 object.

**In summary:** my main class goes like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "application-context.xml");
AudioFileServices audioFileServices = (AudioFileServices) context.getBean("audioFileServices");

AudioFile audioFile = new AudioFile();
audioFile.setAlbum("test");
audioFile.setArtist("test");
audioFile.setLength(1);
audioFile.setPath("test");
audioFile.setTitle("test");

AudioFile a1 = null;
AudioFile a2 = null;

try {
    audioFileServices.saveAudioFile(audioFile);
    a1 = audioFileServices.getAudioFile(audioFile.getIdAudioFile());
    a2 = audioFileServices.getAudioFile(audioFile.getIdAudioFile());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**ISSUE:** Both audioFile1 and audioFile2 are representing the same object, (The same row in the database) however, they are two different instances and not two objects referencing the same instance. (As I wish it would be) Therefore, any modification made to the first object does not affect the second one. (Even though they are both mapped to the same database row)

I have properly configured the application context to inject the AudioFileDAO bean into the AudioFileService bean and am using the Service layer architecture. Everything works perfectly except for this annoying issue. I have also set up transactions and am using the sessionFactory bean that is injected into the AudioFileDAO bean by SPRING as well.

Do any of you know what I am missing here? Maybe it is a HIBERNATE configuration issue?
Any ideas?

Thank you in advance. (I can provide a copy of my application-context, service, and dao code if needed)

Answer (score 0):

How about set a2 = a1, instead of getting from method getAudioFile.

Comment: Hi Gary, Thank you for your answer. My problem is that in this example I am only using the main class in order to expose my issue but I am actually developing a Swing application with multiple views and controller. A specific audio file can then be retrieved from different views that have no links to each other and thus it is impossible for me to use set a2 = a1 although it is primordial all instances referencing this same row in the database reference to the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because Hibernate is not caching retrieved instances of your objects. I would look into [Hibernate Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks,I'm having a look right now. However when retrieving my audioFiles in my actual application I am retrieving them based on the playlist (Also a table) they are contained into.(One audioFile can be contained into several playlists) This means my queries are not findAudioFile(idAudioFile) but findAudioFilesOfPlaylist(idPlaylist). (returns a List) This means the same audioFile can be retrieved from querying the findAudioFilesPerPlaylist method of the playlist1 and of of the playlist2.Would the cache take in account that it returns the same object? Or is it based on the actual query? Thanks

Comment: I'm not famailiar with cahe settings, but I would think that in that case your `List<Song>` in both playlists would contain a reference to the same song.  This assumes you have a join table that has a playlist_id and a song_id.

Comment: yes, I have a join table in order to do so.I've tried implementing a 2nd level cache with hibernate, and even though it does work (It only makes the SELECT query once when the first get is requested and then retrieves the value of the object from the cache when the second get is requested) it does not return the reference of the same object. The cache does not actually stores a reference to the domain object retrieved from the DB, but only the values of its mapped attributes. (Columns)Thus I still have the same issue.It also only works if the second query is exactly the same as the first one.